# How can I incrementally build a plot in an ioslide presentation using Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, plot, presentation, r-markdown

I'm trying to build a plot incrementally on one slide using Rmarkdown to create an ioslides (HTML) presentation. I've tried using {.build} but to no avail, and it seems there is no documentation on this in the Rmarkdown community. Does anyone know how to write this code in R?

Here is a MWE where I try to build a plot in three steps, from a blank plot to a scatterplot to a lineplot, all in one slide where the plots unfold by clicking forward one at a time:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "User"
date: "07/03/2014"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide Title

```{r, echo=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(10)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
plot(1:10,x,type='n')
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
plot(1:10,x,type='p')
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
plot(1:10,x,type='b')
```
````

Any thoughts on how to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the slide title

```
<div class="incremental">
```

And then at the end

```
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to solve the problem -- I'm still getting the plots stacked sequentially and running off the bottom of the slide. Is there another piece of code that needs to be written in the preamble to get your solution to work? Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: Running off the slide? That makes sense. A typical slide can only hold 1-2 images, max. For what you are doing, you want multiple slides in a row. It should have the same effect as overlaying the plots in powerpoint.

Comment: I see. Is there a way then to suppress page numbering, as in LaTeX with Beamer using [noframenumbeing]?