# How to sequentially output partial (base r) plots in rmarkdown/knitr?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Suppose I have the following rmarkdown code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "04/12/2019"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide title

```{r echo=FALSE}
plot(1:10, axes = FALSE, ty = "n")
axis(1)
## Next
axis(2)
## Next
points(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

At each of the `## Next` points I would like to output the current state of the plot, so that I can sequentially reveal parts of the plot. My ultimate goal is to create subsequent slides in an `ioslides` presentation with the sequential plots in them, all from the code above (with the caveat that ideally I would not want later lines of code to be able affect earlier ones, as could occur above).

I would like it to have the same effect as how I'm currently solving it:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "04/12/2019"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

## Set up environment for running the code
env <- new.env()

## Source code to run, as a list of quotes

full_src <- list(
  quote({
    plot(1:10, axes = FALSE, ty = "n")
    axis(1)
    }),
  quote({
    axis(2)
    }),
  quote({
    points(1:10, 1:10)
    })
)

```

## Slide title

```{r echo=FALSE}
# Evaluate first set of lines
eval(full_src[[1]], envir = env)
# Reset environment so later code can't affect earlier code
rm(list = ls(envir = env), envir = env)
```

## Slide title

```{r echo=FALSE}
# Evaluate first and second set of lines
invisible(sapply(1:2, function(i) eval(full_src[[i]], envir = env)))
# Reset environment so later code can't affect earlier code
rm(list = ls(envir = env), envir = env)
```

## Slide title

```{r echo=FALSE}
# Evaluate all lines
invisible(sapply(1:3, function(i) eval(full_src[[i]], envir = env)))
```
````

The slides that are output look like this:

[image: Four slides]

But as you can see, that is clunky and not very general. Important features of a solution would be that the lines of code for the plot is as close together as possible, and only written once; ideally, I could just do this with a chunk option/hook.

The best kind of answer would retain the ability to echo the new lines of code added to the graph (e.g., the ones between the `## Next` markers) yet yield the whole plot up to that point.

What's the best way to achieve this?

**Edit:** Also, I want to be able to group changes to a plot, and not just output every to a new plot, so `fig.keep` won't work.

Comment: Hmmmm... in a document you would set the chunk option `fig.keep = 'all'`, but if you want the outputs on separate slides, you probably need separate code chunks...

Comment: The problem is `fig.keep` would give me four plots, not three, because it retains all changes, not just the arbitrary groups you want (edited to make this clear).

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565438/how-can-i-incrementally-build-a-plot-in-an-ioslide-presentation-using-rmarkdown) to a similar question?  The question is fairly old, so I don't know how relevant it is.

Comment: @aosmith, unfortunately, that does not work; I see the same problem as the first response to the answer (plots run off the page, no new slides are created).

Comment: Does the `.build` attribute do anything for you?  [Section 4.1.3.3](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ioslides-presentation.html#build_slides)  of the R markdown book doesn't have a worked example and [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29902430/2461552) show examples for bullets and not chunk output.

Comment: Excellent question! There is a better way to do it, but I just discovered a bug in **knitr**. I'll post an answer once I fix the bug.

Comment: *"I just discovered a bug in knitr. I'll post an answer once I fix the bug." – Yihui Xie 3 hours ago*... looking down at the answer, *answered 3 hours ago – Yihui Xie*. That's supernaturally fast bug-fixing, Yihui! Way to go!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The chunk option `fig.keep` can take a numeric vector to index the plots, so you can choose the last three plots via `fig.keep = 2:4` (or remove the first plot via `fig.keep = -1`).

To group plots on different slides, you can dynamically add slide titles. You can either use `cat('\n\n## Title\n\n')` with the chunk option `results = 'asis'`, or with `knitr::asis_output()`.

Below is a full example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "04/12/2019"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
new_slide = function(title = '\n\n## Next\n\n') {
  knitr::asis_output(title)
}
```

## Slide title

```{r echo=FALSE, fig.keep=2:4}
plot(1:10, axes = FALSE, ty = "n")
axis(1)

new_slide()
axis(2)

new_slide()
points(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

Note that there is a bug in the current version of **knitr**, which [I just fixed on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/53b968c5e5b0547c17508bc5d7c5de0e5ac52046). For now you need to use the Github version of **knitr**:

```r
if (packageVersion('knitr') <= '1.26')
  remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```

Comment: Excellent! I've included this in my template here: https://github.com/richarddmorey/RcompileSlides/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/morey_presentation/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd which includes a class that prevents the slide number from incrementing. I might also implement javascript that automatically takes the title from the first slide's title, which would prevent having to define the title everytime. But this does exactly what I want; thanks.